# how to stop the same system.out.println("message"); from appearing after the first condition have been met?

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans

I have a gui which asks for a 4 digit pin which I have done however I need help in making the submit button work.

I want the user to enter one of these numbers if correct the ATM(); GUI will open if they enter any number other than what I've defined they get a appropriate message. I don't think I'm doing it correct because it displays the "Incorrect pin try again!" message weather I insert the correct numbers or not. Also its displays the "Incorrect pin try again!" 3x how do I stop that?

the pin which i have defined in the insertpin class are

```
public static final int PIN0 = 1234;
    public static final int PIN1 = 2345;
    public static final int PIN2 = 3456;
    public static final int PIN3 = 4567;
```

this is what I've done for the Submitbutton:

```
if (pin != PIN1){
System.out.println("Incorrect pin try again!");
if( pin == PIN1){
    System.out.println("Hi Mo");
}

if (pin != PIN2){
System.out.println("Incorrect pin try again!");
if( pin == PIN2){
    System.out.println("Hi Mahir");
}

if (pin != PIN3){
System.out.println("Incorrect pin try again!");
if( pin == PIN3){
    System.out.println("Hi Gawi");
    }
```

When I run this and enter either the correct or incorrect pin the system.out.println("Incorrect pin try again!") appears 3 times how do I fix that?

Comment: You can use a switch

Comment: use `if -else if - else`

Comment: I think it should be pointed out that you are checking if `pin` is equal to `PIN1/2/3` inside of the block where you just checked if it *didn't* equal that number, unless you didn't include `}`s that are in your actual code. As @TheQuickBrownFox said, you should use `else if`s here.

Answer (score 4):

You should first check if the PIN matches one of the correct PINs. If yes then print the appropriate message, otherwise print error message

Try this:

```
if( pin == PIN1){
    System.out.println("Hi Mo");
}
else if( pin == PIN2){
    System.out.println("Hi Mahir");
}
else if( pin == PIN3){
    System.out.println("Hi Gawi");
} else {
System.out.println("Incorrect pin try again!");

}
```

Comment: That fixed the duplication problem and I thank you for that, However when I insert the correct pin I still get the Incorrect pin try again! message? should't it return the Hi Mo message?

Comment: @MOHAMEDAHMED you can tweak the logic as you want now. I tried to use the simple logic to help you. And I have used the same base logic as in your code. You were printing 'Hi Mo' in case when pin == PIN1.